# unshare system call doesn't work

Tags: linux, mount, umount

The following simple C++ program attempts to unshare the mount space, mount a USB storage device (located on **/dev/sdd**), waits for input,  and then umounts that device.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <limits> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    unshare(CLONE_NEWNS);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (0 == pid)
    {
        char * mount_args[] = {"/bin/mount", "--make-rprivate", "/dev/sdd", "/mnt", "-o,ro", "-o,noexec", NULL};

        if (0 > execv("/bin/mount", mount_args))
        {
            perror("execv: ");
            exit(1);
        }
        //this line will never be reached.
        return 0;
    }
    else if (0 < pid)
    {
        //parent process!
        int status = -1;
        wait(&status);

        if (0 == status)
        {
            std::cout << "press ENTER to continue....";
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            char * umount_args[] = {"/bin/umount", "/mnt", NULL};
            if (0 > execv("/bin/umount", umount_args))
            {
                perror("execv: ");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
    else
    {
        //fork error!
        perror("fork!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it (after compiling with **-fpermissive**) the mount is visible from every other process on the system.

My goal , of my mounts being invisible to other user-space processes, is clearly not achieved.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: this code doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel version 4.4). It does work on Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel version 4.2) - might this have something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe you have the right to mount it (according to `/etc/fstab`) but not to unmount it?

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `unshare()`, nor of `wait()`...

Comment: Why do you use `CLONE_NEWNS`? Also, why _not_ a call to `umount()`? http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount

Comment: I do have the right to mount (I run the executable as root).

Comment: I do check the return value of unshare() and wait(), I just didn't add that here in order to simplify the code.

Comment: I use `CLONE_NEWNS` as it is is is the way to unshare mount spaces, according to `man 2 unshare`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the OS default mount option has changed in Ubuntu 16. In order to make unshare(2) work, you need to add the following line to your code (prior to the unshare):

```
mount("none", "/", NULL, MS_PRIVATE | MS_REC, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The equivalent on the commandline, using `mount(8)` and `unshare(1)` is: `mount --make-rprivate none / && unshare --mount program [args]`.